# GUI Calculator with no number buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hello I have this calculator and I want it to be buttonless like make the user input in the textfield but I don't know how to make it work like that. I want to simplify it like this but I don't know how to make it work without the number buttons.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class MP2_2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Container c;
JTextField result;
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JButton b[] = new JButton[16];
String s[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "+", "-", "/", "*", "=", "C"};
//----------------------Me------------------------
String Screen = "", monitor1 = "", monitor2 = "", OperationOnScreen = "";
boolean CommandEmpty = true, switcher = true;
double R = Integer.MIN_VALUE, L = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

//------------------------------------------------

public MP2_2() {
    super("MP2_2");
    c = getContentPane();
    result = new JTextField();
    result.setEditable(true);

    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        b[i] = new JButton(s[i]);
        b[i].addActionListener(this);
        p.add(b[i]);
    }
    c.add(result, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(p);

}//End Constructor

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MP2_2 calcu = new MP2_2();
    calcu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calcu.setSize(300, 300);
    calcu.setVisible(true);
}

//------------------------------------------------              

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)//Numbers
    {
        if (event.getSource() == b[i]) {
            Screen += i;
            result.setText("");
            result.setText(Screen);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 10; i <= 14; i++)//Commands
    {
        if (event.getSource() == b[i]) {
            if (result.getText().lastIndexOf(OperationOnScreen) != -1)//prevent exception
            {
                result.setText(result.getText().substring(0, result.getText().lastIndexOf(OperationOnScreen)) + s[i]);
            } else {
                result.setText(result.getText() + s[i]);
            }
            OperationOnScreen = s[i];

            if (switcher) {
                monitor1 = s[i];
                switcher = false;
            } else {
                monitor2 = s[i];
                switcher = true;
            }

            if (monitor1 != monitor2 && monitor2 != "") {
                if (switcher) //execute older,send sign newer
                {
                    Calc(event, monitor1.charAt(0), monitor2);
                } else {
                    Calc(event, monitor2.charAt(0), monitor1);
                }
            }
            if (s[i] != "=") //calc returns 0
            {
                Calc(event, s[i].charAt(0), s[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (event.getSource() == b[15]) //Clear
    {
        Screen = "";
        monitor1 = "";
        monitor2 = "";
        switcher = true;
        CommandEmpty = true;
        result.setText("");
    }
}//end actionPerformed

public void Calc(ActionEvent event, char OpType, String Operator) {
    if (Operator == "=") {
        Operator = "";
    }

    if (CommandEmpty && Screen == "") {
        return;
    } else if (CommandEmpty && Screen != "") {
        R = Integer.parseInt(Screen);
        result.setText(Screen + Operator);
        Screen = "";
        CommandEmpty = false;
    } else if (!CommandEmpty && Screen != "") {
        L = Integer.parseInt(Screen);
        R = Operations(R, L, OpType);//calculate
        Screen = "";
        result.setText("");
        result.setText(R + Operator);
    }
}//End Calc             

public static double Operations(double R, double L, char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return R + L;
        case '-':
            return R - L;
        case '*':
            return R * L;
        case '/':
            return R / L;
    }
    return 0;
}
}//end class
```

EDIT: I guess my question wasn't clear sorry. I wanted my program to support inputs from the keyboard also, How do I do this? So I can finally delete the number buttons like in the picture.

Comment: *"..but I don't know how to make it work without the number buttons."*  But I don't know what your question is.  Do you have a question?  BTW - If I was going this minimalist GUI path, I'd lose the rest of the buttons and hand the lot to a `ScriptEngine` to evaluate when the user 'finishes' a formula with the enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the buttons, you'll need to restore the action of the buttons with a call to result.getText().

Here is the code that works on your number buttons.  It sets the value of Screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)//Numbers
{
    if (event.getSource() == b[i]) {
        Screen += i;
        result.setText("");
        result.setText(Screen);
    }
}
```

Therefore, when you hit your operation buttons, you will need to set Screen.
Here is your loop for Commands.  I added Screen = result.getText(); in the else block.  It worked for me.

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 14; i++)//Commands
{
    if (event.getSource() == b[i]) {
        if (result.getText().lastIndexOf(OperationOnScreen) != -1)//prevent exception
        {
            result.setText(result.getText().substring(0, result.getText().lastIndexOf(OperationOnScreen)) + s[i]);
        } else {
            Screen = result.getText();
            result.setText(result.getText() + s[i]);
        }
```

Comment: What lines do I need rebuilding to be able to use this?

Comment: This question is unclear.  If you are asking about compiling the Java code, you will need to recompile the whole file.